# Custom error pages using django 1.10

Tags: django

Hello I'm newbie in Django,

I'm looking to creating custom error pages to my app and found this site: http://blog.eliacontini.info/post/118617321553/django-custom-error-pages

However the 'render_to_response' is not used in Django 1.10

How do I transcript this code to Django 1.10

With best regards.

Answer (score 1):

`render_to_response()` still works in Django 1.10, but if you want to use the more classical approach, you can use `render()`. Example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def myview(request):
    if request.METHOD == 'GET':
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context, status=404)
```

Comment: Ok, but... where do I deal with the response? According to the site I put in my question there is a status_code to pass through

Comment: The status_code is a keyword argument of `render()`in my example. I updated the code to reflect this, feel free to replace`status=404` with any error code you see fit

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.10 passes three parameters to the page_not_found (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/views/#django.views.defaults.page_not_found)

create a function in your custom exceptions view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def page_not_found(request, exception,  template_name='404.html'):
    return render(request, "page-not-found.html", context=None, status=404)
```

then add this line to your urls.py

`handler404 = 'path_to_exceptions_view.page_not_found'`